# ASP.NET Core PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, psql

Пытаюсь установить PostgreSQL в проект ASP.NET Core. Столкнулся с проблемой.
При установке пакета **Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL** возникает ошибка:

```
Ошибка  NU1107  Обнаружен конфликт версий для Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. 
Установите или укажите прямую ссылку Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.4 на 
проект PSQLProject, чтобы устранить эту проблему. 
PSQLProject -> Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 2.2.4 -> 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 2.2.4) 
PSQLProject -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 
(>= 2.1.1 && < 2.2.0).  PSQLProject
```

Как я понял, конфликт между EF Core и EF Core PostgreSQL. Как я могу установить в проект только PostgreSQL?
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: покажите файл проекта

Comment: Я разобрался. Проблема в несовместимости версий. Установил раннюю версию.